# react native flat list re-renders all items with every new item added

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo, chat, react-native-flatlist

i have a smiple chat system that runs with express/socket io and react native with FlatList
to render the messages.

my problem is that everytime i recieve or send a message , I.E : add a message to the displayed messages  , the whole FlatList gets rerendered which amkes it flicker as you see in the following video [see what happens here!!](https://youtu.be/2VNDN15T0PM)

the way i'm adding the messages to the flatlist is as follows:

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<any[]>([WELCOME_MESSAGE]);
// the following line i use when i get a new message from the server ... and the definition in the beginning of the component (so the problem isn't here...) 
    setMessages([newMessage, ...messages]);
```

and the flat list code itself is as follows :

```
    <FlatList
      inverted
      style={{}}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flexGrow: 1,

        // justifyContent: "flex-end",
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        paddingBottom: 30,
      }}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ChatMessage data={item} key={item._id + ""} />
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
      // keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={loading} onRefresh={onUpdate} />
      }
    />
```

the only useEffect statement in the page is as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", loadMessage);

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  },[navigation]);
```

also when i get a message this is what i do ::

```
  socket.on('update-chat' ,async(data : any)=>{
    console.log('<<<<<<< recieve message <<<<<<<');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('<<<<<<< recieve message <<<<<<<');
    let roomID = '' ;
    await getRoomID().then((data)=>{
            console.log('getting the room id and setting the hook...', data);
            roomID = (data?.headers.room != null)? data.headers.room  : ''; 
    });

    console.log('setting room to use in update chat...');
    // TODO check if we have the room id locally...
      if(roomID != null && roomID === data.roomId && roomID !== ''){
        // TODO ==>  just get the data and start working on the display... 
        // updating display...
        console.log('udpate chat , rooomID : ' + roomID);
        addMessage(data.message);
      }else{
        // TODO ==> store the roomID and then update display...
        // saving the roomID for later use and then update displays...
        console.log('roomID');
        await useRoom.save(data.roomId||'') ;
        addMessage(data.message); 
      }
  });
```

when i text using this app it does as you guys saw in the video and then it becomes really crazy with the re-rendering of components until i get the following error after chatting for a while :

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

and if i keep going after that i get(i'm only getting the following on android devices and i'm not sure it's connected to the issue at hand -i'm including it just in case -):

```
Warning: Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code:
```

after that the app just freezes for a while ...